# How to create a new text file with asp?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

im trying to write a program which create a new text file with asp.
it is giving Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0035'.  However when I change the file  for the line

```
Set f=fs.GetFile("c:\vie4.txt")
```

to an existing file it does not give this error.

> Hello !
>
> Welcome to my Web site!
>
> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0035'
>
> File not found
>
> /simple2.asp, line 33

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1"  method ="post" action = "simple2.asp"  runat="server"  >
    <div>
        <input id="Text1" type="text"  value =  "fname"   />
        <input id="Text2" type="text"  value ="lname" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <%

response.write(request.querystring("fname"))
response.write(" " & request.querystring("lname"))
        fname = request.querystring("fname")
        lname =  request.querystring("lname")

response.write("<p>Hello " & fname & " " & lname & "!</p>")
response.write("<p>Welcome to my Web site!</p>")

Dim fs,f
Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f=fs.GetFile("c:\vie4.txt")
Response.Write("File created: " & f.DateCreated)
set f=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean to create this using the ancient, unsupported, ASP Classic technology?

Comment: Removed C# tag - it was not there in time of ASP-classic...

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sheydkke%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). `GetFile` doesn't create files. Use [`CreateTextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for that:

```
...
filename = "c:\vie4.txt"
If Not fs.FileExists(filename) Then fs.CreateTextFile filename
Set f = fs.GetFile(filename)
...
```

Comment: correct and to the point; but would you remove the spurious () in the .CreateTextFile call?

Comment: Personally prefer `Call fs.CreateTextFile(filename)`  as it allows the use of "spurious" `()` and reads better.

Answer (score 0):

```html
   Table1.Rows.Clear();

            List<Knjiga> knjige = new List<Knjiga>();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Server.MapPath("biblioteka.xml"));
            foreach (XmlElement el in doc.GetElementsByTagName("knjiga"))
            {
                knjige.Add(new Knjiga()
                {
                    ISBN = el.GetAttribute("ISBN"),
                    Naslov = el.GetAttribute("naslov"),
                    Stanje = Int32.Parse(el.GetAttribute("stanje")),
                    Citano = Int32.Parse(el.GetAttribute("citano"))
                });
            }

            knjige = knjige.OrderByDescending(d => d.Citano).ToList();

            foreach (var knjiga in knjige)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                // Cells
                TableCell isbn = new TableCell();
                TableCell naslov = new TableCell();
                TableCell stanje = new TableCell();
                TableCell citano = new TableCell();

                isbn.Text = knjiga.ISBN;
                naslov.Text = knjiga.Naslov;
                stanje.Text = knjiga.Stanje.ToString();
                citano.Text = knjiga.Citano.ToString();

                tr.Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[]{ isbn, naslov, stanje, citano});

                Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
```

Comment: please explain your answer.